# Find the ratio of purchased customer and average of transaction day gap from multiple customers in bigquery or sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following transactions stored in bigquery.

```
CUSID   PID TID YYYYMMDD
A01     P01 001 2017-01-01
A02     P01 002 2017-02-25
A02     P02 002 2017-02-25
A03     P02 003 2017-03-01
A03     P02 004 2017-03-05
A03     P02 004 2017-03-05
A04     P01 005 2017-03-10
A04     P03 005 2017-03-10
A04     P03 006 2017-03-11
A04     P03 007 2017-03-15
```

I would like to find 2 things for a given product as follows:

1) X: the number of purchased customers divided by the total number of customers and

2) Y: the average day gaps of purchasing of all customers

Therefore, the expected output is the following table

```
CUSID  PID  TID YYYYMMDD        X               Y
A01    P01  001 2017-01-01   3/4 = 0.75  AVG(0,0,0) = N/A (P01 does not have re-purchasing by A01, A02, and A04)
A02    P01  002 2017-02-25   3/4 = 0.50  AVG(0,0,0) = N/A (P01 is not re-purchased by A01, A02, and A04)
A02    P02  002 2017-02-25   2/4 = 0.50  AVG(0,4) = 4 (P02 is not re-purchased by A02 but it is re-purchased by A03 for 4 days.  Note: duplicated product in the same TID is excluded, e.g. TID = 004)
A03    P02  003 2017-03-01   2/4 = 0.50  AVG(0,4) = 4 (P02 is not re-purchased by A02 but it is re-purchased by A03 for 4 days.  Note: duplicated product in the same TID is excluded, e.g. TID = 004)
A03    P02  004 2017-03-05   2/4 = 0.50  AVG(0,4) = 4 (P02 is not re-purchased by A02 but it is re-purchased by A03 for 4 days.  Note: duplicated product in the same TID is excluded, e.g. TID = 004)
A03    P02  004 2017-03-05   2/4 = 0.50  AVG(0,4) = 4 (P02 is not re-purchased by A02 but it is re-purchased by A03 for 4 days.  Note: duplicated product in the same TID is excluded, e.g. TID = 004)
A04    P01  005 2017-03-10   3/4 = 0.75  AVG(0,0,0) = N/A (P01 is not re-purchased by A01, A02, and A04)
A04    P03  005 2017-03-10   1/4 = 0.25  AVG(1,4) = 2.5 (P03 is repurchased by A04 for 1 and 4 day gaps)
A04    P03  006 2017-03-11   1/4 = 0.25  AVG(1,4) = 2.5 (P03 is repurchased by A04 for 1 and 4 day gaps)
A04    P03  007 2017-03-15   1/4 = 0.25  AVG(1,4) = 2.5 (P03 is repurchased by A04 for 1 and 4 day gaps)
```

May I have your suggestions?

Comment: What is the difference between a purchased and non purchased customer in your table?

Comment: I would like to observe how much the product is popular in the customers.  So, the purchased customers are any customer who adopts the products and non-purchased customers are any customer who does not adopt the product., e.g. the product P01 has been purchased by three customers A01, A02, and A04 while A03 still does not purchase it.

Comment: You're going to need, at the very least, a table of all customers here.

Comment: Suppose I assume that all customers exist in this transaction table. For X, I think 

SELECT
  L.PID as PID,
  R.NUMCUST as NUMCUST
FROM (
    SELECT
      PID,
    FROM
      MYTABLE
    GROUP BY
      PID) L
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      COUNT(DISTINCT CUSID) as NUMCUST,
      PID
    FROM
      MYTABLE
    GROUP BY PID) R
  ON
    L.PID = R.PID

 should return the number of purchased customers. But I still cannot figure out how to get it done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below does exactly what you described
it is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 'A01' AS CUSID, 'P01' AS PID, '001' AS TID, DATE '2017-01-01' AS YYYYMMDD UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A02', 'P01', '002', DATE '2017-02-25' UNION ALL SELECT 'A02', 'P02', '002', DATE '2017-02-25' UNION ALL SELECT 'A03', 'P02', '003', DATE '2017-03-01' UNION ALL SELECT 'A03', 'P02', '004', DATE '2017-03-05' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A03', 'P02', '004', DATE '2017-03-05' UNION ALL SELECT 'A04', 'P01', '005', DATE '2017-03-10' UNION ALL SELECT 'A04', 'P03', '005', DATE '2017-03-10' UNION ALL SELECT 'A04', 'P03', '006', DATE '2017-03-11' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A04', 'P03', '007', DATE '2017-03-15' 
),
popularity AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT PID, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT CUSID) OVER(PARTITION BY PID) / COUNT(DISTINCT CUSID) OVER() AS X
  FROM data
),
gaps AS (
  SELECT CUSID, PID, TID, YYYYMMDD,
    DATE_DIFF(YYYYMMDD, LAG(YYYYMMDD) OVER(PARTITION BY CUSID, PID ORDER BY YYYYMMDD), DAY) AS gap
  FROM data
),
gaps_without_dups AS (
  SELECT CUSID, PID, YYYYMMDD,
    MAX(IFNULL(gap, 0)) AS gap
  FROM gaps
  GROUP BY CUSID, PID, YYYYMMDD
  HAVING gap > 0
),
average_gaps AS (
  SELECT PID, AVG(gap) AS Y
  FROM gaps_without_dups
  GROUP BY PID
)
SELECT CUSID, PID, TID, YYYYMMDD, X, Y
FROM data
LEFT JOIN popularity USING (PID)
LEFT JOIN average_gaps USING(PID)
-- ORDER BY TID, PID
```

Output is as expected

```sql
CUSID   PID TID YYYYMMDD    X       Y    
A01     P01 001 2017-01-01  0.75    null     
A02     P01 002 2017-02-25  0.75    null     
A02     P02 002 2017-02-25  0.5     4.0  
A03     P02 003 2017-03-01  0.5     4.0  
A03     P02 004 2017-03-05  0.5     4.0  
A03     P02 004 2017-03-05  0.5     4.0  
A04     P01 005 2017-03-10  0.75    null     
A04     P03 005 2017-03-10  0.25    2.5  
A04     P03 006 2017-03-11  0.25    2.5  
A04     P03 007 2017-03-15  0.25    2.5
```

Comment: if my answer helped you  - please also consider voting it up :o)

Comment: It works perfectly.  I have voted for you.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This query might do the trick as well (I used as supposition that if a transaction id is bigger than the other then its date is also bigger):

```
SELECT
  * EXCEPT(lead_date),
  AVG(CASE WHEN lead_date != date THEN DATE_DIFF(parse_DATE("%Y-%m-%d", lead_date), parse_DATE("%Y-%m-%d", date), DAY) END) OVER(PARTITION BY PID) Y
FROM(
  SELECT
    *,
    COUNT(DISTINCT cusid) OVER(PARTITION BY PID) / COUNT(DISTINCT cusid) OVER() X,
    LEAD(date) OVER(PARTITION BY PID, cusid ORDER BY TID) lead_date
  FROM
    data )
```

where `data` is your input data:

```
with data as(
select 'A01' as cusid, 'P01' as PID, 1 as TID, '2017-01-01' as date union all
select 'A02', 'P01', 2, '2017-02-25' UNION ALL
SELECT 'A02', 'P02', 2, '2017-02-25' UNION ALL
SELECT 'A03', 'P02', 3, '2017-03-01' UNION ALL
SELECT 'A03', 'P02', 4, '2017-03-05' UNION ALL
SELECT 'A03', 'P02', 4, '2017-03-05' UNION ALL
SELECT 'A04', 'P01', 5, '2017-03-10' UNION ALL
SELECT 'A04', 'P03', 5, '2017-03-10' UNION ALL
SELECT 'A04', 'P03', 6, '2017-03-11' UNION ALL
SELECT 'A04', 'P03', 7, '2017-03-15'
)
```

When you are running this type of analyzes make sure to use the concept of [analytical functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#analytic-functions).

BigQuery documentation is quite good and you can safely use it to understand everything there is to it.
This will give you the skill to run very complex queries using simpler and faster queries.